# Rotating paths inside an SVG

Tags: css

How do we set the transform-origin of a specific path within an SVG?
I want to rotate something on hover but the transform-origin of the path inside the SVG is that of the SVG itself. Any ideas?

[Hover over the picture of me to see what I mean.](https://zealous-panini-8d66ea.netlify.app/#/home)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a specific part of the SVG to be controlled by CSS, then you need to have the raw SVG code in your HTML file instead of loading it with an image tag.

Then you can locate the path you want and set the `transform-origin` with css there. (if you need to group some paths together, then just wrap them in an extra `<g></g>` tag and chuck an `id` on it then you can target that group)

example (this will rotate your glasses):

```css
#_x31__1_ {
  transform-origin: 50% 30%;
  transition: 1s;
}

#_x31__1_:hover {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```